# Unable to deploy a Deployment after adding Pod Disruption Budget

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes Deployment that has just 1 replica. While upgrading it, after adding the PDB policy, it has two pods in the Pending state, scheduled after my deployment, and one running long before it.

The PDB policy is as follows:

```
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: <name of the app>
spec:
  minAvailable: 90%
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <name of the app>
```

Is it the case that this pod will never be evicted during an upgrade?